# Intermittent lag in command terminal?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-gnome, vim

I have a workstation that we run numerical simulations on using in-house code, submitting jobs from the command line and using vim to edit/view files. My problem is that whenever we are running at least one job (not even up to full capacity of CPUs available), we see intermittent lag in the command line while there is no lag in the gnome desktop. The command line will seize up. Most notably when using vim to save files it will almost always take 10-30 seconds to save even the simplest one line files. Has anyone faced a similar problem or have any ideas? We are using kernel 6.2.0-26-generic and ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Thanks

Comment: What's the Disk IO look like?  (ie: `iotop`)

Comment: Do you have swap enabled? `free` will tell you. Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: @earthmeLon This is what I see when running this command: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DjpYDDWT7z6YVE5EQLUNdrN6Dqd1XU-a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @waltinator Yes I believe I do. Here is the output from that command: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9B6msi1yKukNIoweXqPWRzQYTJxJv9h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the forum.

### System Resources

This seems like a hunt to find which system resource is insufficient but we can't tell because there is not enough information.  You could provide details like:

```
df -h
uptime
iostat -d -k -x 1 1 | awk '/^sda/ {print $NF"%"}'
sudo dmesg | tail
```

However, I think it would be better to look through the system logs yourself and provide one or a few happening when the issue occurs.

### Separate the Tasks

One easy win I can see is to just separate your scripts from vim file editing.

- Log into a separate computer (could be a very simple Ubuntu instance on a Raspberry Pi Zero or a VM)
- SSH into the Ubuntu system in question
- Edit files with vim

This will only require the Ubuntu system in question to save changes to the file versus an interactive session.

### Best Solution

This is really what Docker is great for.  You limit system resources being accessed while gaining insight into what the task is requiring for resources.  "Numerical simulations" and "in-house code" sound like a great use case for the versioning functionality as well.

### USB Bus

Using Time Machine backups from a USB flash drive causes my keyboard/mouse to lag.  When it happens, I can use my bluetooth, directly connected track pad just fine.  Breaking up tasks would help identify a problem with the USB bus.

### Session Logging

This is probably overkill but you could record the terminal session and review the log to see what's happening.  Here's how:

1. From Terminal

   `script session.log`

Replace session.log with the filename you want to save the log as. This will start recording your terminal session to the specified file.

2. Reproduce the actions that are causing the lag in the terminal.
3. When finished type `exit` to stop recording the session.
4. View the log file.
5. Look for any commands/actions that might be causing the lag, or errors/output that might indicate the cause.

Note: this includes any commands you enter, their output, and any error messages.  The file can get large quick.

Comment: Hi musicman1979, thanks for the timely reply. Here is the session log file section where the lag is occurring. I have highlighted the location where the lag is occurring in the middle of editing a file using vim. It occured after editing the file and typing ":wq". This is where the highlighted portion starts. It hangs for about 20 seconds until finally coming back to the main folder out of the file.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w3U1ZjEI-S4bVZpawhzJpDtblZIa_5s7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, here is the output from those original commands you listed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vk32aohkJl-X0B_4hicgu72hwqIy-e5b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is the highest cpu utilization I can remember ever seeing.  If it wasn't causing you problems I would be impressed.  What uptime shows is the percentage of processing your computer is doing over 1, 5, and 15min (`man uptime`).  0.50 would be 50% and 1.50 is 150%.  If we consider the load average in the context of a single CPU system, a load average of 107.92 indicates that there are on average 107.92 processes waiting in the run queue over the specified time intervals.  I'm interested how it even works, but I think this is the reason for the slowness.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind marking this as the answer and making a new post for planning the solution I would appreciate it.

Comment: Our workstation uses AMD EPYC9754S and it does not have SMT (128 cores/128 threads). Our code is also highly parallelized to the point where many CPUs will be at 100% capacity a lot of the time.  Could this be the reason why we are seeing such high load average?

Comment: wow 256 processors.  okay that means <50% utilization.  images are a lot harder to work with than text.  dmesg had some apparmor errors 5 seconds apart.  I think you'll have to dig deep into logs to understand what's going on.  If you can provide some specific log entries showing the problem then I can help further.  Also, jumping from a different computer and running vim would help to understand the problem.  Does it happen if you're directly connected with monitor keyboard mouse?  If this is a routine task, then the file should really be in a git process.  :wq! will force and may be faster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152110/discussion-between-musicman1979-and-stl).